# Trying to up UIViewController and MapKit

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, mapkit

So I'm attempting to make a calendar app. In this app it allows users to put in a location in their events for travel time (similar to how iOS maps do it.) However, I'm having trouble populating the ListView that I have under the TextField... below is the code and the result.

Code to update ListView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CustomTableViewCell
        let request = MKLocalSearch.Request()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = locationSearchTextField.text
        request.region = mapKitView.region
        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
        search.start(completionHandler: {(response, error) in
            if error != nil{
                print("Error occured during search:")
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                numberOfResults = 0
                tableView.isHidden = true
                return
            }else if response!.mapItems.count == 0{
                print("No results found")
                numberOfResults = 0
                tableView.isHidden = true
                return
            }else{
                print("Results found")
                matchingItems = (response?.mapItems)!
                numberOfResults = matchingItems.count
                tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: numberOfResults)
                print(numberOfResults)
                let indexRow = indexPath.row
                let matchingItemsCount = matchingItems.count
                if(matchingItemsCount > indexRow){
                cell.nameLabel.text = matchingItems[indexRow].placemark.name
                }else{
                    return
                }
            }
        })
    return cell
}
```

Code to track when a user edits the TextField (this code is used to update the ListView):

```
@IBAction func locationTextFieldChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    tableView.reloadData()
    tableView.isHidden = false
}
```

the result:
[image: result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making this call in an external function like:
Each time you make a call, if you have results, update your array and then call `tableView.reloadData()` at the end, so it will create necessary cells for you.

```
func makeSearchCall() {
    let request = MKLocalSearch.Request()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = locationSearchTextField.text
    request.region = mapKitView.region
    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
    search.start(completionHandler: {(response, error) in
        if error != nil{
            print("Error occured during search:")
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            numberOfResults = 0
            tableView.isHidden = true
            return
        }else if response!.mapItems.count == 0{
            print("No results found")
            numberOfResults = 0
            tableView.isHidden = true
            return
        }else{
            print("Results found")
            matchingItems = (response?.mapItems)!
            numberOfResults = matchingItems.count
            tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: numberOfResults)
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    })
}
```

Then in your `cellForRowAt` method:

```
guard let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as? CustomTableViewCell else {return UITableViewCell()}
cell.nameLabel.text = matchingItems[indexPath.row].placemark.name
return cell
```

Also in your `numberOfRowsInSection` method:

```
return matchingItems.count
```

Comment: Holy hell it worked... do you mind explaining why what I was doing wasn't working? I've literally been stuck on this for around 6 hours now.

Comment: Also, I would like to mention for future reference to anyone looking at this that in the cellForRowAt method you need to change the cell to optional, resulting in:

guard let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as? CustomTableViewCell else {return UITableViewCell()}

you also need to wrap the line setting your label name in an if function to make sure that matchingItems is holding a value, or you'll get an out of range error:

if(matchingItems.count > 0){
cell.nameLabel.text = matchingItems[indexPath.row].placemark.name
}

Comment: I'm glad it worked out, cellForRowAt, is not a good place to make your search calls or anything that updates data. cellForRowAt method is just a place to deploy your cells, and tell the table view how you are going to bind your cell's subviews with your data. Thats why, you should make any updates in another method, and once you update your dataSource, then by calling tableView.reloadData, you let tableView now that dataSource is updated and cells are re-created for new data in cellForRowAt method. @cdunn2013

Comment: Thanks so much... I'll keep that in mind. You're a life-saver!